# How to extract a specific file without its folder structure using the 7za command

Tags: unix, extract, unix-utils

I have a zip file (my.zip) consisting of 4 files:

- mydata_20050523-20130113.csv
- mydata_20050523-20130113FileHeader.csv
- my Data Association - Code Values.pdf
- my Data Association - Readme.pdf

out of which I need only one file: "mydata_20050523-20130113.csv". The other 3 are supporting documents.

I tried to use the command below:

```
7za x my.zip -x!*FileHeader.csv -x!*.pdf
```

This used to work previously as the files were directly extracted without any folder structure. However, now when extracting there is a directory structure which is extracted underneath which the files are present. So it is not working.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Doesn't `7za x` extract with full paths, and `7za e` extract without paths? Try changing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-xr0` switch with a wildcard:

```
7za x my.zip -xr0!\*/FileHeader.csv -xr0!\*.pdf
```

Explanation: [`-x`](http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/include.htm) operates only on filenames by default and doesn't support recursion. `-xr0` will operate on subdirectories ([`r`](http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/recurse.htm)) and allows the use of wildcards in these (`0`).

Comment: A little more explanation would go a long way to making this a better answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works and my issue is resolved.

Comment: You're welcome, and don't forget to "accept" my answer so that others who have the same problem will find it more easily.